# How to Compare Sharepoint to fileshare?

Tags: migration

I have migrated about 50000+ files and folders from fileshare to Sharepoint Library.

But seems like some files are missing and sharepoint migration tools logs wont really make sense regarding to missing files.

Is there a way to compare these 2 ? I have tried excel but it keeps crushing.

Would you know a good script and how can i use it please? i dont have many experience with scripts?

Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

You could access SharePoint through your file explorer (just punch in the URL in your file explorer, but authenticate with IE first.)

Maybe compare the contents of two folders with an external tool like WinMerge.

There are some file types SharePoint generally disallows to be uploaded to a library. Maybe this info can help you:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3#ID0EAABAAA=2013,_2010